# Case statement while using join in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can we use case statement at joins

I need to join based on condition like

```
if month(fr_yr) <= month(to_yr)
then
join on start date between month(fr_yr) and month(to_yr)
else
join on start date between month(to_yr) and month(fr_yr)
```

while selecting the data

Thanks,

Comment: Do left joins, add month(fr_yr) <= month(to_yr) to join conditions.

Comment: can you please help to be more specific

Comment: You should include your table definition along with some data.  If nothing else, it would make your question more useful.

Comment: hi have tried as below  select a inner join b on case When month(fr_yr) <=month(to_yr) then start date between month(fr_yr) and month(to_yr) else start date between month(to_yr) and month(fr_yr)  but i am getting error as invalid systnax near between

Comment: Clarify SQL engine... SQL-Server, MySQL, etc...

Comment: i am using sql server 2008

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Doing `between` on `month()` just looks like an error.

Comment: Since `between` is always unsatisfied if given a first parameter larger than the second, you could just write `start date between month(fr_yr) and month(to_yr) or start date between month(to_yr) and month(fr_yr)` (Assuming suitable escaping of `start date`). But I think I share many of Gordon's reservations here. Some sample data, expected results, and (if you think it's relevant), how you got to this point in your solution would add a lot to this question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Exactly what I was thinking.  Why the case statement at all?

Answer (score 1):

SQL's join syntax is so general it can be used to simulate relational operations (the classic one is `OUTER JOIN` to perform a `UNION`). I suppose it can get to the point where you think you always *need* a join. But it is worth remembering the relational operators analogous to logical `OR` e.g. `UNION`:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM YourTable 
 WHERE start_date BETWEEN month(fr_yr) AND month(to_yr)
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM YourTable 
 WHERE start_date BETWEEN month(to_yr) AND month(fr_yr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any valid logical statement as a join condition, and you can use a case expression as part of such statement.

So you can do something like this:

```
create table #t1 (i int)
create table #t2 (i int, j int)

insert #t1 values (1), (2)
insert #t2 values (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 1), (5, 2)

select *
from #t1
join #t2 on #t1.i between case when #t2.i<=#t2.j then #t2.i else #t2.j end and case when #t2.i<=#t2.j then #t2.j else #t2.i end
```

How will this affect the performance is another story, of course. Personally, I'd rather UNION ALL two queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bizarre requirement.

Here is your join clause that you need (no need for unions, temp tables, or anything overly complex)

```
ON StartDate BETWEEN MONTH(fr_yr) AND MONTH(to_yr)
OR StartDate BETWEEN MONTH(to_yr) AND MONTH(fr_yr)
```

Answer (score -1):

No you can not do that. 
You can not use if conditions to change the joins within a select statement 
you can use the following join clause

```
join on startdate between month(fr_yr) and month(to_yr) 
OR
startdate between month(to_yr) and month(fr_yr)
```

Comment: I sort of understand the answer, but the upvotes make no sense.   Presumably, the `if` would fail immediately with some sort of undefined value error.

Comment: Why would it fail ? I don't think it would.

Comment: Assuming fr_yr and to_yr are in valid datetime format. The if condition would not fail. I have tested this on sqlserver2008. Why do you think it will give an error ? @GordonLinoff

Comment: You might want to also consider - at the moment, in the question, these values are not being shown as *variables* at all, and could thus, presumably, be *column* references. As such, the correct action to take may be different on a *row by row* basis.

Comment: yes you are right the values might not be variables. But I made the logical assumption that the values are infact variables, because I assume if they are column references the values would already be in a structured format and there won't be a reason for if condition. So the values are more likely parameters passed by the user.

Comment: @Sam . . . Variables in SQL Server start with `@`.  What identifier would `fr_yr` and `to_yr` be?

Comment: @GordonLinoff .. Thankyou for pointing that out. That didn't came my mind at the time. I have edited the answer now.